# iOS: HTTP Live Streaming to app, Video won't play

Tags: ios, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

I'm have some video files ready for streaming on my server. Here's the code I'm trying to use to play them in an iOS app:

```
    Video *vid = [videos objectAtIndex:index];
    NSURL *vidUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:vid.videoUrl];
    NSLog(@"%@",vid.videoUrl);
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:vidUrl];
    player.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    [player.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];
    [player play];
```

If I copy and paste the URL the NSLog spits out into Safari, the video plays fine. So I know the URL is good. But in my app, I just get a black screen. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MPMoviePlayerController` needs to be a strong property declared as so `@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *mvpc;`

Then whenever you want to play a movie you would write:

```
self.mvpc = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"movieURL"]];
self.mvpc.shouldAutoplay = YES; //Optional
self.mvpc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
[self.mvpc prepareToPlay];
[self.mvpc.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.mvpc.view];
[self.mvpc play];
```

Comment: The reason is the fact that the `MPMoviePlayerController` needs to be retained, otherwise it will be freed immediately. 
Since nothing within the system retains it, you have to do that yourself. To retain it, you can establish a strong property/instance within your class, covering that job.

Comment: Appreciate that Till, thank you for the explanation.